# wice_grid (ruby on rails): ERB to SLIM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

I'm using the [wice-grid gem](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid).

Their examples show the views in `.erb` but I'd like to use `.slim` for my project but am having trouble converting the example `erb` into working `slim`.

```
# ERB renders and works perfectly
<%= grid(@tasks_grid) do |g|

  g.column do |task|
    task.id
  end

  g.column  do |task|
    task.title
  end
end -%>
```

```
# Converted SLIM does not render properly
- grid(@tasks_grid) do |g|
  - g.column do |task|
    = task.id

  - g.column  do |task|
    = task.title
```

I've tried using this [erb2slim](http://erb2slim.com/) converter but it outputs `end` which `slim` doesn't allow.

Edit:
**Solution** (thanks to the help below!)

```
# Generate grid
- grid = grid(@tasks_grid) do |g|
  - g.column do |task|
    - task.id

  - g.column  do |task|
    - task.title

# Render content in a safe way
= content_tag(:div, grid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= grid(@tasks_grid) do |g|
  - g.column do |task|
    - task.id

  - g.column  do |task|
    - task.title
```

`=` is equal to `<%=` in ERB templates. It outputs the expression. `-` evaluates but does not output like `<%` in ERB. If you look at the erb template you can see that it just outputs the return value of `grid(@tasks_grid) do` not `task.id`.

Also note that converters rarely do the job to 100% and are not a replacement for knowing both the original and target language. They just provide a starting point to make the process less ardous.

Comment: The ERB template has `<%=` outputting the entire block for `grid(@tasks_grid)`. I've tried changing the slim version to:

Comment: Yeah sorry that first character should have been =. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's almost there. 

After converting to the example above, I'm able to render a string that contains the html for the table. To get it to actually display as html, I did `- table_output = grid(@tasks_grid) do |g|` then after the block, rendered it: `= table_output.html_safe`. It's a bit more convoluted than I'd like but manageable. 

Do you have any suggestions on a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: In slim you can't just call a method on `end` like you would in ERB so thats probally the cleanest way to do it  in the template. You could write a method that wraps `grid` and calls `super.html_safe`. But I don't really get why you are calling .html_safe on the whole thing. And that's probally not the best idea in the first place. https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong